# Find the limit points of $\left\{\frac{1}{m}-\frac{1}{n}:m,n \in \mathbb N^+\right\}$

Tags: real-analysis, limits

Find the limit points of $\left\{\frac{1}{m}-\frac{1}{n}:m,n \in \mathbb{N}^+\right\}$.

I read a lot posts related to limit points of $\left\{\frac{1}{m}+\frac{1}{n}:m,n \in \mathbb N^+\right\}$ is $\left\{ 0 \right\} \cup \left\{\frac{1}{n}:n\in \mathbb N^+\right\}$. Now I want to know the result of subtraction here.

So when both $m$ and $n$ are going to infinite, $\left\{0\right\}$ is the limit point. When only $m$ is going to infinite, set $A=\left\{-\frac{1}{n}:n\in \mathbb{N}^+\right\}$ is its limit point. Similar, set $B= \left\{\frac{1}{m}:m\in \mathbb{N}^+\right\}$ is the result when only $n$ is going to infinite.
The answer just need to put these three parts together. Am I on the right track?

Comment: You have correctly determined the limits points of the set, but can you show you have found all of them? As a hint, take an arbitrary limit point and apply the sequential definition to proceed from there, distinguishing between the cases where the limit is positive, negative and zero.